# Ubuntu Precise system headers moved somewhere else and sys/ucontext.h cannot be found

Tags: 12.04, 10.10, g++

I'm in the process of porting some applications from Maverick 10.10 to Precise 12.04. Some of the system headers do not seem to be in the same place. This is giving me some headaches since it doesn't seem to matter that i add the include paths.

In particular, on Maverick, there was a file in `/usr/include/sys/ucontext.h`, and this file defines the constant `REG_EIP`. Now, on Precise, this file has moved to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ucontext.h`, but g++ 4.6 nor 4.7 have that include path:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

the consequence of this is that when including `#include <ucontext.h>`, `REG_EIP` is not defined

I've tried adding `#include <sys/ucontext.h>` but i still get the error:

```
error: 'REG_EIP' was not declared in this scope
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **symbolic link** using this on a terminal:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ucontext.h /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h
```

If `/usr/include/sys/ucontext.h` already existed, you may want to rename it before:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h.backup
```

If anything went wrong, you can remove the symlink and restore the backup:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h
$ sudo mv /usr/include/sys.ucontext.h.backup /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h
```

Comment: This is such an awfully bad solution, that i would most likely downvote it, if it wasn't for the small fact that it is, with great likelihood, also the best possible solution available, given the known constraints of poor architectural and engineering decisions happening at ubuntu. I wouldn't go as far as upvoting it either. I will leave it sit a while, i will catch my breath tomorrow, or probably the day after, probably kick and punch some stuff at the gym, and after i get my morning coffee, i will accept this answer, unless a better one shows up. Also will ponder on other lines of work.

Comment: and of course, this situation carries on exactly the same to other distros based on Precise and Quantal, such as Linux Mint 13 and 14.

Comment: failure, for some reason this is not working, i've softlinked the whole /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys folder to /usr/include/sys, but still getting the same error... no idea what is going on